# Is $\frac{1}{2^{2^{0}}}+\frac{1}{2^{2^{1}}}+\frac{1}{2^{2^{2}}}+\frac{1}{2^{2^{3}}}+....$ algebraic or transcendental?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, power-series, irrational-numbers, transcendental-numbers

Inspired by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1580331/131263), the series $\dfrac{1}{2^{2^{0}}}+\dfrac{1}{2^{2^{1}}}+\dfrac{1}{2^{2^{2}}}+\dfrac{1}{2^{2^{3}}}+\dots$ is clearly irrational.

But is it algebraic or transcendental?

---

I was thinking of answering this question by checking whether or not it can be represented as a **periodic** [continued fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction):

- If no, then (as far as I know) it is transcendental
- If yes, then (as far as I know) we cannot infer the answer

But how do I determine whether or not it can be represented as a periodic continued fraction?

Is there a better way for tackling this question, or is the answer already known by any chance?

---

**UPDATE:**

Based on @Wojowu's comment:

- If it can be represented as a periodic continued fraction, then it is algebraic
- If it cannot be represented as a periodic continued fraction, then we cannot infer the answer

Comment: Continued fraction seems to link to the "Ask Question" page. Is there any reason for this?

Comment: Aperiodicity of continued fraction would only tell you the number is _not_ a quadratic irrational (it could still be algebraic). Periodicity would tell you it's a quadratic irrational, hence algebraic.

Comment: This is relevant: http://mathoverflow.net/a/24197/30186

Comment: @Element118: Ooops, sorry. Thanks :)

Comment: @Wojowu: Wait, I thought $e$ has a periodic CF, yet it is transcendental... Which part did I get wrong?

Comment: CF of $e$ isn't periodic. It has the form, iirc, $[2;1,2,1,1,4,1,1,6,...]$ in which arbitrarily high coefficients appear.

Comment: @Wojowu: Oh, right. I guess I've mixed "periodicity" with "an observable pattern" (which, for example, $\pi$ is not known to have as far as I know).

Comment: @Wojowu: Regarding your "this is relevant" comment above - doesn't this link essentially answers my question?

Comment: It does :) ${}{}{}$

Comment: Periodic continued fractions represent irrational quadratic numbers (elements of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{a})$ with $a\in \mathbb{Q}$ that is not a perfect square). Unless you found some clue that might indicate it is quadratic I really doubt testing for such a small family of algebraic numbers is going to be of any help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a general theorem proven by Mahler that given an integer $d>1$ and a nonzero algebraic number $z\in(-1,1)$ then the sum of the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^{d^n}$ is a transcendental number. I can't find a direct reference, but you can find this theorem in [this MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/24190/sum-of-subset-of-geometric-series-a2n/24197#24197).

Transcendence of the number in your question follows by taking $d=2,z=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Thanks. I'll wait a little while longer just to be sure that nobody thinks otherwise...