# what is $\int_{1}^\infty \frac{x!}{x^x}dx$?

Tags: definite-integrals

I plugged in this integral on desmos $$\int_{1}^\infty \frac{x!}{x^x}dx$$
and it said it was undefined. I see no reason this should be undefined because $\frac{x!}{x^x}$ goes to 0. What is this integral or is it just undefined?

Comment: Maybe it does not recognize $x!$ for non integer values of $x$.

Comment: The factorial function is only defined on the integers, so this integrand is undefined for most values. You can try replacing it with $\Gamma(x+1)$, though I'm not sure Desmos will be able to handle it.

Comment: How do you define the factorial of, say, $\pi$?

Comment: It probably doesn’t know how to interpret $x!$ for non-integer $x$. If you replace that with $\Gamma(x+1)$ it will likely work.

Comment: "because the integrand goes to 0" this really isn't a good justification considering $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{x}=0$ but $\int^\infty_0 \frac{1}{x}\,dx\to\infty$.

Comment: By Stirling's formula, $\frac{{x!}}{{x^x }} \sim \sqrt {2\pi x} e^{ - x}$, so the integral converges fast. I do not think there is a simple closed form for it though. Its numerical value is $1.33056689850038\ldots$. It may also be expressed as $$
\int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{(1 + t - \log t)t}}{{(t - \log t)^2 }}e^{ - t} dt} .
$$

Comment: Yeah, I do know that the integral converges, just pointing out that the justification provided is invalid. I do know that [$\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{n!}{n^n}=\int^1_0\frac{1}{(1+x\ln x)^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1185875/prove-that-sum-n-1-infty-fracnnnis-irrational?noredirect=1), but I can't figure out how to use similar methods to get a closed form for the integral, even while using special functions.

Comment: @Kyky My message was to the OP. Your point is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 2):

As @Gary commented, using Stirling approximation, we have
$$\frac {x!}{x^x}\sim\sqrt{2 \pi }\, e^{-x} \sum_{n=0}^p \frac {a_n}{x^{n-\frac 12}}$$
$$\int x^{-n+\frac 12}\,e^{-x}\,dx\sim-\Gamma \left(\frac{3}{2}-n,x\right)$$
$$\int_1^\infty x^{-n+\frac 12}\,e^{-x}\,dx=\Gamma \left(\frac{3}{2}-n,1\right)$$
$$\int_1^\infty \frac {x!}{x^x}\,dx\sim\sqrt{2 \pi }\,\sum_{n=0}^p {a_n}\,\Gamma \left(\frac{3}{2}-n,1\right)$$ Using the first $a_n$
$$\left\{1,\frac{1}{12},\frac{1}{288},-\frac{139}{51840},-\frac{571}{2488320},
   \frac{163879}{209018880},\frac{5246819}{75246796800},-\frac{534703531}{9029
   61561600},\cdots\right\}$$  leads to a value of $1.330533$

**Edit**

If we write
$$\frac {x!}{x^x}\sim \sqrt{2 \pi x}\,\exp\Big[-x+\frac{a}{ x} \Big]$$ the antiderivative of the rhs write in terms of exponentials and complementary error functions and the definite integral is
$$\frac{e^{-1-2 i \sqrt{a}} \left(e \pi  \left(\left(1+2 i \sqrt{a}\right)
   \text{erfc}\left(1-i \sqrt{a}\right)+\left(1-2 i \sqrt{a}\right) e^{4 i
   \sqrt{a}} \text{erfc}\left(1+i \sqrt{a}\right)\right)+4 \sqrt{\pi } e^{a+2
   i \sqrt{a}}\right)}{2 \sqrt{2}}$$ For $a=0$ the result is
$$\frac{\pi  \text{erfc}(1)}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{\sqrt{2 \pi }}{e}=1.27157$$ and for $a=\frac 1 {12}$
$$\frac{\sqrt{2 \pi }}{e^{11/12}}+\frac{\left(3+i \sqrt{3}\right) e^{-\frac{i}{\sqrt{3}}} \pi 
   \text{erfc}\left(1-\frac{i}{2 \sqrt{3}}\right)+\left(3-i \sqrt{3}\right)
   e^{\frac{i}{\sqrt{3}}} \pi  \text{erfc}\left(1+\frac{i}{2
   \sqrt{3}}\right)}{6 \sqrt{2}}=1.33139$$

Comment: The only problem is that the series in Stirling's is divergent.

Comment: @Gary. I know but I thought that it could be better than $\frac{\pi  \text{erfc}(1)}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{\sqrt{2 \pi }}{e}=1.27157$

Comment: Yes but then your equalities are meaningless. After integrating from $1$ it is not even an asymptotic series anymore since there is no large variable in it. That numerical series diverges to infinity.